# Automapper 2 source fields mapped to 1 destination field

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 classes to be mapped:
class1 has fields PaymentState and PaymentStateId

```
public int PaymentStateId { get; set; }
        
[ForeignKey(nameof(PaymentStateId))]
[InverseProperty(nameof(PaymentStateEntity.OrderEntities))]
public virtual PaymentStateEntity PaymentState { get; set; }
```

class2 has field with the same name PaymentState but of enum type

```
public PaymentState PaymentState { get; set; }
```

while mapping class1 to class2 there is an error that field PaymentState cannot be mapped:

```
Unable to create a map expression from
class1.PaymentState (Entities.PaymentStateEntity) to PaymentState.PaymentState (Enums.PaymentState)

Mapping types:

class1-> class2

Destination Member:

PaymentState
```

have tried custom mapping fields, but I guess that the fact that there are 2 fields now which are to be mapped to 1 destication field makes the problem

```
CreateMap<class1, class2>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.PaymentState, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PaymentStateId))
```

What is the way to ignore one source field though let another source field to be mapped to destination field?

Comment: Your question seems to confuse `PaymentType` and `PaymentState` - it's not entirely clear how `PaymentType` and `PaymentTypeId` are relevant to the question (perhaps they aren't?). That aside, isn't the issue that you don't have a map configured for `PaymentStateEntity -> PaymentState`?

Comment: will correct the question, i've mentioned payment type by mistake
thank you

Comment: You are on the right track with configuring the mapping with `CreateMap`. Is the mapping configuration used? Does it lead to an error? Usually, AutoMapper needs to know a mapping for the destination fields. So it is no problem if a property of the source class is not used in the mapping.

Comment: adding 2 rules for the same field helped (1 for ignoring, another as it was - custom mapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the error cause is 2 fields mapped into 1 destination. Probably because of the difference of type between dest and source. You should check log what the error is.
But you can try to use

```
CreateMap<class1, class2>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.PaymentState, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForMember(dest => dest.PaymentState, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PaymentStateId))
```

Besides, you can convert 2 enums by setting their items to have the same value

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.PaymentState, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (PaymentState)((int)src.PaymentState)))
```

Comment: thank you
adding 2 rules helped - 1 for ignoring the field and another for custom mapping